# What is the function of a service pack on a software?

Tags: windows, driver, servicepacks

Whenever i installed a software , it don't allow to install because my system not contain service pack 1 (on windows 7 PC) . What is the  function of a service pack 1 on a software . assume If i install that software with out service pack , it's functionality will change ? or works fine ? please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service pack contains the updates to the known and latest bugs that have been identified by Microsoft Developer Network. It helps in stability and security of the system.

The functionality might change depending on what;s included in the update but generally the updates available via Windows update are part of Service pack releases.